# Running Multiple Sites from Common Composite C1 CMS

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

I am wondering if we can have multiple sites connected to same composite C1 CMS? We are planning to create a mobile version of our site so the best bet would be if we can control the content of both sites through "One Common CMS" system.

I am thinking about folder structure like:

"Project Folder"(level1) -->> "WebSite(Composite C1) folder" (level2)

```
      -->>"MobileSite (Composite C1) folder" (level2)
```

i.e mobile site is at same level as of main site

But that way those will be 2 separate installations both pointing to same database but i am concerned about state information and other details those composite store while saving content back to the database.

So the second structure could be :

"Project Folder" (level 1)  -->> "WebSite(Composite C1) folder" (level 2) ->>"MobileSite (Composite C1) folder" (level3)

i.e mobile site as sub folder of main site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Composite C1, you can create more than one website. Each website has its own homepage (the root page of the website).

In 2.1.1 version you have ability to [associate different host names with different websites](http://docs.composite.net/HTML/FrontendFAQ?q=How%20to%20associate%20different%20host%20names%20with%20different%20websites%20in%20C1?) in C1 (on the Content perspective, right-click a home page (the root page of a website) -> click Manage host name.)

In 2.1.3+ version you can run multiple sites by using new ->[Configuring hostname bindings](http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Configuration/UrlConfiguration).

Comment: Thanks for the response Inna. Yes i figured that out using Configuration hostname bindings. Cheers!!